# Distributing Python and dependencies on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu

My goal is to be able to package a fully-functional Python interpreter and all dependencies.  Couple of quick thoughts up front:

- I can't install via pip/requirements.txt on due to Firewall restrictions.  I will only have access to pip install on the build system.
- Maintaining an internal repo wouldn't be feasible
- The code to be distributed will be a number of tools/utilities, not a single script (not as straight-forward to use 'freeze' utilities)
- I'm attempting to avoid third-party tools that don't have a strong community.
- I'm not using the version of Python packaged with the OS (Ubuntu uses 3.5, we'll likely be using 3.6)

My plan was as follows:

1. Create a Docker container for the target OS (Ubuntu)
2. Download Python source and manually build it with a prefix of /build
3. Use the full path to Python to install dependencies with Pip.  For example:

   ```
   /build/bin/python3.6 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
   ```
4. Tar up the /build directory with the Python runtime and all dependencies
5. All scripts and utilities will use the absolute path to the interpreter such as:

   ```
   /opt/python/bin/python3.6
   ```

Does anyone see any glaring issues with this plan?  I was able to build successfully, move the package to another host, and import all of the pip installed dependencies (requests, numpy, psutil, etc.)

Comment: The explanation of how sys.path is derived from the docs makes sense why this would work from an imports perspective: https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html

Still a bit concerned there might be something I'm not thinking about here.

Comment: are you targeting only Ubuntu? (might help to update your question title with this as well) . perhaps you can look into using Snappy ? (I have no experience with it but it sounds like it's there for these purposes)

Comment: I've updated the title, but I would figure that if it worked on one platform, the approach would likely work on others.  Do you have a link to Snappy?  It seems like a pretty overloaded name.  The results I'm seeing don't appear related.

Comment: You could use https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv to manage Python version instead of building it from source. This also isolates dependences. Also, with this you might not require docker to achieve your goal.

Comment: I’ll look into pyenv for the interpreter part of the install.  I know that Docker isn’t truly necessary here, but it is a bit faster and more reproducible that building on an Ubuntu VM.  Also, the build system at work supports Docker, but not Ubuntu directly.

Comment: Snappy: https://docs.snapcraft.io/snaps/intro